# Keeping model name as root key with StrongParameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, strong-parameters

Is there a way with `StrongParameters` to keep the model name as hash root?

For instance, when I submit the form which creates a user, my params look like

```
<ActionController::Parameters {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"...", "user"=>{"full_name"=>"first last", "email"=>"me@example.com"}, "button"=>"", "controller"=>"admin/users", "action"=>"create"} permitted: false>
```

Notice that they contain `"user"=>{...}`. 
However, after sanitizing them with StrongParamyetes

```
  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:full_name, :email)
  end
```

I get

```
<ActionController::Parameters {"full_name"=>"first last", "email"=>"me@example.com"} permitted: true>
```

without `"user"` at the root key.

I know, I can add it manually

```
  def user_params
    { user: { params.require(:user).permit(:full_name, :email) } }
  end
```

but I'm wondering if there is an option I can set to get that behavior by default on all my controllers.

Thank you.

**UPDATE 1 (the use of `user_params`)**

```
#users_controller.rb
def create
 if MyFancyFancyObject.call(user_params)
    redirect_to users_path, 
  else
    render action: "new"
   end
end
```

Comment: is there any specific reason why you're doing this?

Comment: Yes, indeed there is a reason. Without losing focus with too many details which are not relevant to the issue, I can say that having the model name as key allows me to extract duplicated code from my lower layer. Currently, I have multiple objects that do the same but they are different since in addition to the params they must know the class to use. With the name inside the params, I can have one single object.  Thanks

Comment: where do you sanitizing with StrongParamyetes in controller ? i am not getting your question what you really want.

Comment: @Vishal I have added my `create` action. FYI, when I`MyFancyFacyObject.call` returns either `true` or `false`. Hope this gives you the full picture.

Comment: @macsig MyFancyFancyObject is it model or service ?

Comment: @Vishal `MyFancyFancyObject` is a plain Ruby object. Anyway, I don't see how this is relevant to the question. Thank you.

Comment: @macsig So you mean to say whenever you pass `user_params` in `MyFancyFancyObject` than in that class, you get parameters without user root. right ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm wondering if there is an option I can set to get that behavior by default on all my controllers.

No, there isn't. What you're trying to do is simply not how StrongParameters works. As soon as you `params.require(:user)`, you're returning the nested set of values associated with that key.

Your only option is to manually build a new hash, as you suggest:

```
def user_params
  { user: { params.require(:user).permit(:full_name, :email) } }
end
```